# Mongoose update query keeps on inserting data with upsert true without updating and adding only 1 field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on Facebook login in Node js with Mongoose. i am getting issues while updating data.

This is my Scheme file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 // Schema
var RegSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    UserName: String,
    UserEmail: String,
    userprofileImage : String,
    userId: String,
    reg_time : {
        type : Date, default: Date.now
    }
}, { collection: 'user' });

// Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserReg', RegSchema);
```

and this is my main file where update and insert(if not found) is placed

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 



var UserReg = require('./myschema.js');

module.exports = function(userdetail, callback){
var bb;

                  var UserAdd = new UserReg({
                                "UserName": userdetail.username,
                                "UserEmail": userdetail.useremail,
                                "userId": userdetail.userId,
                                "userprofileImage": userdetail.userprofileImage
                            });

                    var userdetailchange = {
                                "UserName": userdetail.username,
                                "UserEmail": userdetail.useremail,
                                "userId": userdetail.userId,
                                "userprofileImage": userdetail.userprofileImage
                    };

                    // Update if found otherwise Insert
                    UserAdd.update({"userId":userdetail.userId },{ $set:userdetailchange, $setOnInsert:userdetailchange ,upsert:true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            } 
                                callback(data);                             
                    });

};
```

Now it keeps on inserting user data in collection with only 1 field which is userId and also a default _id field. Please help me in updating whole data if match found or Insert whole data in Collection. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upsert`, `new` and `setDefaultsOnInsert` are options, which need to be passed in a separate, third argument to `update` (documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)):

```
UserReg.update({
  "userId" : userdetail.userId     // query document
}, {
  $set         : userdetailchange, // update document
  $setOnInsert : userdetailchange
}, {
  upsert              : true,      // options
  new                 : true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert : true
}, function (err, data) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: if i placed options separate then its giving me error. callback.apply() is not a function.

Comment: @noobcode I think you mean `UserReg.update()` instead of `UserAdd.update()`, see edit.

Comment: Thank You Robert. its working now. highly appreciate you.